# Getting "Unable to check for available memory." on Oracle DB 18c

Tags: java, database, oracle18c, oracle-enterprise-manager, dbca

I am trying to create a database in order to complete my self learning, but unfortunately I got unexpected error "Unable to check for available memory.", I am doing it using Database Configuration Assistant (DBCA).

[image]

**My Oracle Database Version**

[image]

Comment: May be you can try running the dbca as administrator `Run as Administrator` in Windows or `sudo dbca` in Linux.

Comment: I have tried that but no luck happened, still the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following parameter to bypass the error:

```
dbca -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false &
```

Comment: hi I will try later and let  you know the result

Comment: by the way, could you explain what is the param doing?

Comment: DBCA is not able to check the amount of available memory on your system, the parameter above causes the validation checks to be skipped.

Answer (score 6):

This error as it says, indicate that the "DBCA" can not check for available memory. This happens when "DBCA" does not have permission to check.

To bypass this error, run your Command Prompt as Administrator before lunching "DBCA".

Answer (score 1):

Bypass via advanced setup

Run DBCA as admin and work your way through the advanced setup. I think this issue is avoided because it lets you manually enter, or use recommended defaults, for the memory section.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone reading is running into the above issue and find that

> dbca -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false &

didn't fix it for them, consider launching the advanced configuration setup for a database. (There's a radio button listed on the "Creation Mode" step). Its pretty straight forward and avoids the validation steps. That's how I got around the issue

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, Oracle 19 setup. I installed Oracle without creating a database, because of this memory error.

Then

I ran cmd as administrator

I added "dbca -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false &" to the dbca.bat first if statement at the bottom of the file

I switched off all options.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but when on the second stage of creating a database I select option "pluggable" and enter the name, it works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Steps:
Rename your PC Name
Restart and again start installation

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem. I had previously installed Java 18.0.1.1 X64 bits
By removing it and restarting the system, the problem was solved.
Apparently, Java should not be installed on the machine before creating the database.

Answer (score -1):

For Me i was facing this issue while doing normal setup for Oracle Database 19c , and renaming your PC name did work for me . the issue can be understand as below -

In my case this was a permissions issue on the Oracle Home directory. If your Windows PC name is >= 16 characters in length, the name of the administrators group is affected, because only the first 15 characters are included. The mismatch between that first part of the name and the full name is what was causing the issue. DESKTOP-ASUS-ROG vs. DESKTOP-ASUS-RO in my case (notice the missing G). I renamed the PC to DESKTOPASUS, restarted the machine, and it worked without issue. The name discrepancy was apparent when looking at the security configuration of the folder when my system name was over max.

You can get your PC name by running hostname from the command line. If it's >= 16 characters, rename the PC to be <= 15 characters, and restart.

The underlying issue is indirectly discussed here in a different context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/naming-conventions-for-computer-domain-site-ou

Maximum name length: 15 characters.