# Oracle XE 18c create database error "[DBT-50000] Unable to check for available memory" through DBCA

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-xe, oracle18c, dbca

I have just installed Oracle XE 18c on my Windows 8.1 machine.

I am trying to create a new database through **Advanced Configuration** but when I get to **Configuration settings** step, it throws an error:

> ***[DBT-50000] Unable to check for available memory***.

I have tried bypassing the validation checks as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019218/getting-unable-to-check-for-available-memory-on-oracle-db-18c) but still no luck.

I have also tried creating it through command prompt with:

```
dbca -createDatabase -silent -gdbName ora18c -templateName General_Purpose.dbc 
-sysPassword sys123 -systemPassword sys123 -dbsnmpPassword sys123 -
datafileDestination /u01/oradata -storageType FS -memoryPercentage 20 -
emConfiguration NONE -sampleSchema false -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false
```

but it also throws in an error saying Oracle not available.

I highly appreciate your help please.

Comment: Does 18c XE even allow to create multiple instances? This wasn't possible in 11 XE

Comment: If you are installing on Windows, why are you specifying a linux type directory ('/u01/oradata') as a file destination?

Comment: @EdStevens sorry that was just an example I used. Before I ran it, I edited it into my windows directory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not entirely sure hey. I will do a bit of research on that. Maybe that is my problem.

Comment: For future reference, if you want help with something, then you need to show what you actually did.  This _should_ be self evident.

Comment: @EdStevens, my apologies. I will be sure to next time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in a future build of XE. In the mean time can you try the following.

1) On your network adapter that you are using, check (enable) "Client for Microsoft Networks" and "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks".

2) Check to see if Netbios is enabled on your network connection:
See this link for more info:

http://ecross.mvps.org/howto/enable-netbios-over-tcp-ip-with-windows.htm

3) In some cases, antivirus has interfered with an installation. Try disabling anti-virus and reinstall..

I'm afraid at this point this is all I can suggest.

Comment: Let me test it. will get back to you with results. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Dom G, It turns out that my antivirus was the one interfering with my system. I did as suggested and temporarily uninstalled the antivirus and my oracle installation, I then re-installed my Oracle and it worked smoothly. I installed back my antivirus after setting up my database and all is well. Thank you soooo much for your time and suggestions. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

It may seems outrageous, but I just run cmd as administrator and then I opened dbca and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle 19c Installation in Windows 10 need to follow below few steps and this is mandatory.

DBCA fails with Errors: [FATAL] [DBT-50000] Unable to check for available memory.

Solution:- "Set Virtual Memory in Windows".

```
Right Click on "This PC" 
-> Properties -> Advanced System Setting 
-> Advanced -> Setting -> Advanced -> Change(Virtual Memory)
-> Custom Size(Initial Size = RAM*2, Max Size = RAM*4) 
-> OK
-> Run cmd as administrator and then opened dbca and it will work.
```

Note :- Please don't give wrong answer if you don't know exactly. Because it will kill so much times of thousand people. Please remove your answer if you don't know.

Comment: what does it actually mean to set Initial Size and Max Size?
How does that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug (Bug 29686671). I'm not aware of a know work around. But I will take a look and see it's possible to work around it.

Some people have had success turning off parameter verification.

```
dbca -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false
```

It is fixed in future XE releases but I realise this doesn't help you now.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will be waiting for your feedback @Dom G

Comment: Yes, this one doesn't help because I've tried it before also but it still brings back the same error.

Answer (score 1):

before run DBCA at command window, open cmd(command Prompt) as Administrator in Windows. it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and Easy Way:

"Run DBCA as Administrator"

It worked for my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the above-posted solutions don't work check your Computer system Name.
The software apparently runs into some kind of error when your system name consists of spaces, special symbols. So just try to keep the name as simple as possible like admin or user. Mine was dell-Inspiron-user123 I changed it to user123 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this issue is,

Run dbca with “-J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false” like a bellow command,

```
$> dbca -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as [Dom G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482015).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 related issues , depends when are you facing this issue , based on that you have to do the solution

1. FOR DBT-50000 Error - Unable to check for available memory :
   dbca.bat file is available in bin folder of your installation , if you run this file by right clicking - selecting run as administrator this will work .
2. FOR INS-35180 - Unable to check for available memory :
   Also , For your information , you might face this issue during installation , and not while setting up your DB by running DBCA, then you will have to check if your PC name is > 15 characters , if so change name to have less then equal to 15 characters to solve this issue

For Me i was facing this issue while doing normal setup for Oracle Database 19c , and renaming your PC name did work for me . the issue can be understand as below -

In my case this was a permissions issue on the Oracle Home directory. If your Windows PC name is >= 16 characters in length, the name of the administrators group is affected, because only the first 15 characters are included. The mismatch between that first part of the name and the full name is what was causing the issue. DESKTOP-ASUS-ROG vs. DESKTOP-ASUS-RO in my case (notice the missing G). I renamed the PC to DESKTOPASUS, restarted the machine, and it worked without issue. The name discrepancy was apparent when looking at the security configuration of the folder when my system name was over max.

You can get your PC name by running hostname from the command line. If it's >= 16 characters, rename the PC to be <= 15 characters, and restart.

The underlying issue is indirectly discussed here in a different context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/naming-conventions-for-computer-domain-site-ou

Maximum name length: 15 characters.